# OpenCV 2.4.8 and VS2013 Crash on DrawContours

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I have been pretty frustrated since I installed vs2013. My code on vs 2010 all worked well for more than a year and a few days ago I had to upgrade to vs2013. Since the first run I keep getting into a crash at the point where i `drawContours()`. It is seems that the code is trying to access outside the bounds/list/collection of contour points. The same code runs absolutely fine with VS2010. Could this be a vs2013(VC++) bug?

Comment: Are you sure you are linking correct version of OpenCV?

Comment: You mean linking to the correct lib files? Yes I am. I haven't tried the release version. The problem is happening on the debug versions.

Comment: Yes, the correct `lib` files and `dll` files. They are different for VS2010 and VS2013. When using VS2013, make sure to link the lib files present in `vc12` folder in opencv build directory.

Comment: I did cross check and it seems that I have linked them correctly. Both the dlls and the libs for vc12. May be I need to rebuild them myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be true when I sensed to build opencv myself. I had to build all of opencv in VS2013, And then had to make PATH variable to point to the bin directory of the newly built files and then had also place the folder locations for the newly built .lib files in VS. All working fine now.

But the other half turned out that VS2013 did not save my the changes I made to lib files e.g. I renamed some files from *245d.lib to *248d.lib but VS did not save them. That was pretty strange.